# Redirect the user after a form submission

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have an `<input type="text" />` as a search bar inside a `<form>`.

Because it's a search bar the user should be redirected to a route similar to : `/search?q=thingIWantToSearch` when the form is submited.

Currently I'm doing with a `location.href` but I don't think this is a good way of doing it (or is it?)

Here's my code :

```
<script>
    let inputValue = '';

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        // there should be some parsing before putting it in the url, but it's not the subject
        location.href = `/search?q=${inputValue}`;
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" bind:value={inputValue} />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

So how can I properly redirect the user on form submission?

Comment: Look into the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), specifically the `replaceState()` function.

Comment: @BennyHinrichs is this "friendly" for sapper's router ?

Comment: @BennyHinrichs sapper seems to give an `id` property to `history.state` that increment every time something is pushed to the history. That mean a `replaceState()` should manually increment the `id` to keep the history intact. The issue is if sapper change his way to manage the history, it could create some unexpected bugs and force me to update every redirections.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the Sapper tag!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using SvelteKit you can use the built-in `goto` function from `$app/navigation`. Previously [Sappers goto function](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options) served the same purpose.

Here's how you can use it:

```
<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

  let inputValue = '';

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // there should be some parsing before putting it in the url, but it's not the subject
    goto(`/search?q=${inputValue}`);
  };
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault="{handleSubmit}">
  <input type="text" bind:value="{inputValue}" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks you !

Comment: |preventDefault did the trick for me! Thanks a lot <3

Comment: this works in sveltekit as well

Comment: In SvelteKit use: import { goto } from '$app/navigation';